# How to get object titles from JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have some json file from url which I want to format.
Problem is there i dont know how to get only titles of this objects.
I think it should looks like:
 1. Get JSON
 2. Create an array which include only titles "C-402-621, C-393-643, C-389-643..." from this json.

Here is JSON

```js
{  
   "data":{  
      "C-402-621":[  
         23944,
         21469,
         10160,
         "abc",
         0,
         0,
         ""
      ],
      "C-393-643":[  
         31424,
         21469,
         10160,
         "def",
         0,
         0,
         ""
      ],
      "C-389-643":[  
         31713,
         21469,
         10160,
         "gfd",
         0,
         0,
         ""
      ],
... and it goes like this 100+ times till end.
```

**For example I want result looks like:**

```js
"402|621 393|643 389|643 ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` loop and string manipulation. First using `Object.keys` we get all the keys of the `data object`. These keys then can be iterated one by one and with `substr` we can remove first 3 characters and using `replace` we can replace `-` by `|`

```js
var a=[{  
   "data":{  
      "C-402-621":[  
         23944,
         21469,
         10160,
         "abc",
         0,
         0,
         ""
      ],
      "C-393-643":[  
         31424,
         21469,
         10160,
         "def",
         0,
         0,
         ""
      ],
      "C-389-643":[  
         31713,
         21469,
         10160,
         "gfd",
         0,
         0,
         ""
      ]}}]
     var data=Object.keys(a[0].data)
     data.forEach((e)=>{data[data.indexOf(e)]=e.substr(2).replace('-','|')})
     console.log(...data)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you need the keys (within the `data` sub-object).
2. Second, you need to split each key by the dashes.
3. Next you need to grab the tail (ignoring the 'C')
4. Then join the values with a pipe.
5. Finally, you can join the processed keys with spaces.

```js
var jsonData = {
  "data": {
    "C-402-621": [
      23944,
      21469,
      10160,
      "abc",
      0,
      0,
      ""
    ],
    "C-393-643": [
      31424,
      21469,
      10160,
      "def",
      0,
      0,
      ""
    ],
    "C-389-643": [
      31713,
      21469,
      10160,
      "gfd",
      0,
      0,
      ""
    ]
  }
};

console.log(Object.keys(jsonData.data).map(x => x.split('-').splice(1).join('|')).join(' '));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a script in nodejs that reads the contents of the file, save it in a variable and pass them in the following function

```
var obj = { data: { .... } };
var keys = Object.keys(obj.data);
```

now keys contains an array of all the keys in your object. To print it like your example you could do

```
console.log(keys.join("|");
//"402|621 393|643 389|643 ..."
```